# Mongoid: (Replication) configuration file yml not loaded

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid, yaml

```
development:
  hosts: [[database_1.mongolab.com, 12345], [database_2.mongolab.com, 12345]]
  database: database_name
  username: database_user
  password: database_pass
  persist_in_safe_mode: true
  raise_not_found_error: false
```

This configuration file (config/mongoid.yml) is loaded using :

```
Mongoid.load!("config/mongoid.yml")
```

But I get this error :

```
Mongo::ConnectionFailure at /
Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? During a deploy? If so, are you using heroku?

Comment: I get this error in local development.

Comment: When though? -- When trying to start the server? When trying to access a instance of a model? When exactly? I seem to remember the asset pipeline not respecting the mongoid.yml during asset pre-compilation, that is why I'm asking.

Comment: The server starts without any errors, but when I try to access an instance of a model it raises this error. thanks for your help.

Comment: Did my answer work for you and make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work because I'm using sinatra and not rails.

Comment: Take a look at the way configuration is done in this project: https://github.com/croaky/sinatra-mongoid is that what you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your mongoid.yml and place it anywhere you like. But be sure that on application path `(config/initialization)` under that you do the following:

```
Mongoid.load!("path/to/your/mongoid.yml")
```

**Update**

To use mongoid master in your project, set this in your Gemfile

```
gem "mongoid", :git => "git@github.com:durran/mongoid.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Sinatra configuration scheme when using Mongoid with Rails.

Try this:

```
development:
 hosts:
 - - database_1.mongolab.com
   - 12345
 - - database_2.mongolab.com
   - 12345
 database: database_name
 username: database_user
 password: database_pass
 persist_in_safe_mode: true
 raise_not_found_error: false
```